# How to use dots_indicator in Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am using dots_indicator 2.0.0 in Flutter and it works perfect for IOS and Android. However, I am testing on the web and it does not work (It does not allow scrolling with the mouse from one side to the other and does not show any error messages).

My stateful code related to dots_indicator is as follows...

Initstate...

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    _pageController.addListener(() {
      if (_pageController.page!.round() != currentIndex) {
        currentIndex = _pageController.page;
        print('Current Index: $currentIndex');
        setState(() {});
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Building pages...

```
  Widget _crearPages(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> _pages = [];
    _pages.add(Page1());
    _pages.add(Page2());
    _pages.add(Page3());
    _pages.add(Page4());

    
    return Stack(
      children: [
        PageView(
                children: _pages,
                controller: _pageController,
                onPageChanged: (int page) {
                  currentIndex = _pageController.page;
                },
              ),
        _dotsIndicator(context, _pages.length),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Dots Indicator...

```
    Widget _dotsIndicator(BuildContext context, int dotsCount) {
    final _size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
      return Positioned(
          bottom: 11.0,
          width: 200.0,
          left: (_size.width-200.0)/2,
          child: DotsIndicator(
            dotsCount: dotsCount,
            position: currentIndex!,
            decorator: DotsDecorator(
              activeColor: (dotsCount == 1) ? Colors.transparent : Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            ),
          ),
        );
  }
```

Is dots_indicator really compatible with Flutter Web?

**How can I make dots_indicator work on the web?**

Answer (score 1):

you need to create custom scroll behavior class like that

```
class MyCustomScrollBehavior extends MaterialScrollBehavior {
  @override
  Set<PointerDeviceKind> get dragDevices => {
        PointerDeviceKind.touch,
        PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
      };
}
```

and add `scrollBehavior` property to `MaterialApp` widget

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      scrollBehavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(), // <- this one
      home: HomePage(), // your widget 
    );
  }
}
```

also read this https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/default-scroll-behavior-drag

Comment: Mmmm... thanks @nagual. According to the document that you share with me, scrolling is not recommended when the device is a mouse. Is there any other property of dots_indicator that I can use that is better than scroll to go from page to page?